# What is LUA in the context of MSI?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I was surprised to see the following appear in an MSI (Windows Installer) log of a pure Windows environment, where the [Lua programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29) has never set foot:

> MSI (s) (A0:60) [19:14:59:585]: MSI_LUA: Setting AdminUser property to 1 because this is the client or the user has already permitted elevation

What is this LUA in this context?

I have found a [few](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesfi/archive/2007/05/02/making-an-msi-that-doesn-t-need-a-uac-lua-prompt.aspx) [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rflaming/archive/2006/09/30/uac-in-msi-notes-how-do-i-troubleshoot-uac-in-msi-via-the-log.aspx) [articles](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=26207) mentioning it but no explanation of what LUA actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the development of Windows "Longhorn" (which eventually became Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008), there was much discussion about the principle of least privilege, and the [Least-privilege User Account (LUA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480194.aspx) that would be at the core of this.

Before its release, [LUA was renamed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uac/archive/2006/01/18/514527.aspx) to UAP (User Account Protection) and then renamed again to UAC (User Account Control). While almost everything user-facing was updated, the verbose log messages from Windows Installer [retain their use of LUA as `MSI_LUA`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rflaming/archive/2006/09/30/uac-in-msi-notes-how-do-i-troubleshoot-uac-in-msi-via-the-log.aspx), the original acronym.

Answer (score 0):

It stands for [Least User Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) (principle of least privilege).

MSI is trying to adjust the execution level to not higher than needed.

LUA's buddy in the MSI world is UAC (User Account Control).

Comment: Yes, in this context LUA is an earlier name for what became UAC. It was never changed in the Windows Installer log strings.

Comment: @MichaelUrman: I didn't know that! Could you please post this as an answer? It would be more informed than mine.